# ¿Cuales son las restricciones para el uso de la licencia GNU GPL?

Tags: animation

tengo una duda respecto a la licencia de Blender. Averiguando en wikipedia pude ver que Blender tiene una licencia GPL, la cual es una licencia de software de código abierto robusta fuerte.
Las licencias de software de código abierto robustas fuertes o con copyleft fuerte, contienen una cláusula que obliga a que las obras derivadas o modificaciones que se realicen al software original se deban licenciar bajo los mismos términos y condiciones de la licencia original.
Mi pregunta entonces es, ¿qué se entiende por obra derivada? ¿Un corto o pelicula que pueda llegar a hacer con Blender? Si elaboro en Blender una animación, modelo 3d, cortometraje o película, ¿tendré los derechos de autor sobre lo que hice? ¿O se aplica a esto el copyleft? ¿Las producciones audiovisuales(cortos, películas etc.)  que haga en Blender serán forsozamente videos libres? (como los que aparecen en esta página https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_libre) ¿Podré lucrar con lo que realice en Blender? ¿Tendré derecho o copyright sobre lo que haga o será de dominio público y cualquiera podrá modificarlo? Espero que se entienda mi pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for Blender Stack Exchange. If you are not comfortable writing in English, please use any online translation service

Comment: Also licensing and legal questions are off topic here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pardono mi espanol pobre. Se entiende que tu puede derivar un CODIGO que tiene de ser GPL tambien.

Todas las obras de audiovisivo son exclusiva propriedad del autor, sin problemas, lucros tambien.

Comment: muchas gracias :)